# Trying to upgrade from Magento 1.6.2.0 to 1.7.0.2 via downloader fails

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've tried to upgrade my existing 1.6.2.0-Installation to 1.7.0.2 via the downloader by the following command:

./mage upgrade http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force

This results in the following message:

Already installed: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.6.2.0, skipping
[...]
[...]

But if I'm checking "./mage list-upgrades" I can see that there is an update for Mage_All_Latest:

Mage_All_Latest: 1.6.2.0 => 1.7.0.2

Next I tried to install 1.7.0.2 by the following command:

./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force

but this (re-)installs only the 1.6.2.0-Packages.

I also tried this two commands setting explicit version numbers but is still doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Go to http:///downloader
Log in using a user who has full permissions
Make sure to select “Clear all sessions after successful install or upgrade”